# How to draw a ring-like diagram with some labels on its arcs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks

I would like to draw a figure that looks like the following scenario:

Consider a circle of radius `$r$`, described parametrically by `$x = cos(t) and y =  sin(t)$`. I'd like to draw a figure where the 90 to 180 degrees arc and the 270 to 360 arc are stretched by adding 1 to the previous point, while keeping the figure connected. Here is a sketch of the figure below: (x and y axis should not be included in the final figure).

[image]

The respective labels are `$\Omega_1$`, `$\partial \varphi(1)$`, `$\partial \varphi (1)$`, `$t=0$`, `$t=1$`, `$t=0$`, `$t=1$`, `$\phi^2$`, `$\Omega_2$`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is part of the picture that I have drawn:

```
\begin{pspicture}(-.5,-.5)(3.5,3.5)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-.5,-.5)(3,3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray]
{
 \psarc(0,0){2.5}{0}{90}
 \psarcn(0,0){1.5}{90}{0}
 \closepath
   }
   \rput(2;45){$\Delta \mathfrak{M}$}
    \end{pspicture}
```

I'd also like to have an additional label `$\Delta \mathfrak{M}$` in each annulus as well as for them to be shaded.

Comment: It'd be swell if you could show us something that you have tried so far- perhaps [Draw arc in tikz when center of circle is specified](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66216) might help to get you started...

Comment: @cmhughes I understand how to draw arcs, but not how to connect them, nor how to label them properly

Comment: so are you drawing an annulus, perhaps like this: [How to shade a partial annulus](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139818)

Comment: @cmhughes it would be two annulus shapes and two arcs, along with the labels

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,transform shape]
\draw (1,0) arc (0:90:1);
\draw (-1,0) arc (180:270:1);
\draw[fill=gray!30] (-1,0) -- (-2,0) arc (180:90:2) -- (0,1) arc (90:180:1);
\draw[fill=gray!30] (1,0) -- (2,0) arc (0:-90:2) -- (0,-1) arc (-90:0:1);
\node at (0.2,0.75) {\tiny $\phi^2$};
\node[rotate=50] at (-0.7,0.5) {\tiny $t=0$};
\node[rotate=50] at (0.7,-0.5) {\tiny $t=0$};
\node[rotate=50] at (-1.45,1.2) {\tiny $t=1$};
\node[rotate=50] at (1.45,-1.2) {\tiny $t=1$};
\node[rotate=50] at (-1.6,1.4) {\tiny $\partial \varphi (1)$};
\node[rotate=50] at (1.6,-1.4) {\tiny $\partial \varphi (1)$};
\node at (-2,2) {\tiny $\Omega_1$};
\node at (2,-2) {\tiny $\Omega_2$};
\node at (-1,1) {\tiny $\Delta \mathfrak{M}^2$};
\node at (1,-1) {\tiny $\Delta \mathfrak{M}^2$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to add a $\Delta \mathfrak{M}^2$ and $\Delta \mathfrak{M}^2$ in each annulus, as well as to shade them light gray?

Comment: In the middle of each annulus, horizontal.

Comment: As well as upscaling

Comment: 898 characters.

Comment: I seriously hate arcs in tikz

Comment: @ADP: According to the PGF/TikZ documentation: TikZ's arc was developed  with the shortcomings on PSTricks' arc in mind.

Comment: @Marienplatz maybe, but everything is a riddle. Like how to do arc centered at (x,y) with radius Z, going from angle ThetaA to ThetaB in degrees.

Comment: @ADP: There are several questions dealing with this, see e.g. [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69420/7279).

Comment: @TomBombadil Thanks. That is what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

With the next version of TikZ it is *finally* possible to place nodes along `arc`s. This is used here with the CVS version of TikZ. (Although, it is relatively easy to calculate the positions and rotations here manually.)

For more information, refer to

- [How can I update TikZ/PGF?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56406/16595)
- [How to place a node in the middle of an arc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38763/16595) (and many more)
- [Draw arc in tikz when center of circle is specified](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66216/16595)
- [TikZ: using the ellipse command with a start and end angle instead of an arc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123158/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, declare function={smallR=2; bigR=2*smallR;}, delta angle=90,
  my ring sectors/.style={fill=gray, nodes={midway, sloped}}]
\filldraw[my ring sectors]
  (left:smallR) arc[radius=smallR, start angle=180, delta angle=-90] node[below] {$t=0$}
   -- (up:bigR) arc[radius=bigR, start angle=90]                     node[below] {$t=1$}
                  node[above] {$\partial\varphi(1)$} -- cycle
  (right:smallR) arc[radius=smallR, start angle=0, delta angle=-90]  node[above] {$t=0$}
  -- (down:bigR) arc[radius=bigR, start angle=-90]                   node[above] {$t=1$}
                   node[below] {$\partial\varphi(1)$} -- cycle;

\draw[radius=smallR] (right:smallR) arc[start angle=0]
                      (left:smallR) arc[start angle=180];
\node[below] at (up:smallR) {$\phi^2$};
\path (-bigR,bigR) -- 
  node[at start]   {$\Omega_1$}
  node[near start] {$\Delta \mathfrak{M}^2$}% or at (135:.5*bigR+.5*smallR)
  node[near end]   {$\Delta \mathfrak{M}^2$}% or at (-45:.5*bigR+.5*smallR)
  node[at end]     {$\Omega_2$} (bigR,-bigR);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: 1171 characters.

Answer (score 4):

Exploiting the symmetrical properties of the diagram in question with PSTricks. It only consumes 583 characters.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\SpecialCoor
\degrees[8]

\def\Atom#1%
{%
    \pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray]
    {
        \psarc(0,0){4}{2}{4}
        \psarcn(0,0){2}{4}{2}
        \closepath
    }
    \foreach \A/\B/\C in 
    {   
        1.7/0/t=0, 
        3.0/1/\Delta \mathfrak{M}^2, 
        3.7/0/t=1, 
        4.3/0/\partial \varphi (1)
    }
    {
        \rput{\ifnum\B=1 *0\else *1\fi}(\A;3){$\C$}
        \rput{*0}(-4,4){$\Omega_#1$}
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
    \Atom1
    \rput{4}{\Atom2}
    \pscircle[dimen=m]{2}
    \rput(1.7;2){$\phi^2$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to the answers already given:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\tikz{\foreach\i in{0,180}
 \path[rotate=\i,fill=gray,draw=black](0:0)--(0:3)arc(0:-90:3)--cycle;
\fill[draw=black,fill=white]circle[radius=1.5];
\foreach\i in{1,2}
 \foreach\r/\s[count=\c]in{5/t=0,8/\Delta\mathfrak M^2,11/t=1,20/\Omega_\i,13/\partial\varphi(1)}
  \node[rotate={mod(\c,2)*45}]at(\i*180-45:\r/4){$\s$};
\node at(90:1.25){$\Phi^2$};}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 446 chars, it is the fewest! +1 you can save  more by moving `tikz` as the class option.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my crack at it. I personally find the notation `draw(x1,y1) to[in=A,out=B](x2,y2);` much easier to work with, as opposed to the crypto mind-bending arc and friends which makes me want to go and drink something strong.

@Jake made a great suggestion to replace with `bend right=45` or `bend left=45` instead which is even easier to understand.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathpazo}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{e/.style={rotate=45},
                 n/.style={e,anchor=north},
                 s/.style={e,anchor=south},
                 f/.style={fill=lightgray},
                 bl/.style={bend left=45},
                 br/.style={bend right=45},}
        \draw   (2, 0) to[br] (0, 2) 
                (-2,0) to[br] (0,-2);
        \draw[f](0, 2) to[br] (-2,0) -- (-4,0) to[bl] (0, 4) -- (0, 2) 
                (0,-2) to[br] (2, 0) -- (4, 0) to[bl] (0,-4) -- (0,-2);
        \node[anchor=north]at (0,2){$\phi^2$};
        \node at (-4,4){$\Omega_1$};
        \node at (4,-4){$\Omega_2$};
        \node[n] at (-1.4,1.4){$t=0$};
        \node[s] at (1.4,-1.4){$t=0$};
        \node[n] at (-2.8,2.8){$t=1$};
        \node[s] at (2.8,-2.8){$t=1$};
        \node[s] at (-2.8,2.8){$\partial \varphi(1)$};
        \node[n] at (2.8,-2.8){$\partial \varphi(1)$};
        \node at (-2.1,2.1) {$\Delta \mathfrak{M}^2$};
        \node at (2.1,-2.1) {$\Delta \mathfrak{M}^2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: You can simplify things a bit further by using `bend left=45` and `bend right=45` instead of specifying the `in` and `out` angles.

Comment: Don't forget to cancel the rotation applied to `\Delta...`. 1073 chars.

Comment: @Jake That suggestion is great. I have made modifications accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Countdown=`457` characters (`Asymptote`,`Linux`).
`ring.asy`:

```
size(220);
usepackage("amssymb");
draw(unitcircle);
string[] s={"$\partial\varphi(1)$","$t=0$","$t=1$","$\Omega_","$\Delta\mathfrak{M}^2$"};
real[] d={2,1,2,-2,-1,-2};
pair[] p={NW,SE,SE,SE,NW,NW};
guide r=arc(N-N,2,90,180)--arc(N-N,1,180,90,CW)--cycle;
filldraw(rotate(180)*r^^r,gray);
for(int i=0;i<6;++i){
  label(rotate(45)*s[i%3],d[i]*NW,p[i]);
}
label("$\phi^2$",N,S);
label(s[3]+"1$",3NW);
label(s[3]+"2$",3SE);
label(s[4],1.5NW);
label(s[4],1.5SE);
```

To get a standalone `ring.pdf`, run `asy -f pdf ring.asy`.

Comment: It does not need `\documentclass`?

Comment: @Marienplatz: AFAIK, for the moment for non-`inline` standalone mode it uses 
`\documentclass[12pt]{article}` as default.

Comment: Interesting: I usually find that when I do something with both Asymptote and TikZ, the Asymptote code is a bit longer. But that's probably because I deliberately write in a style that values robustness over compactness, and dividing a task into several lines of code is more natural in Asymptote than in TikZ.